# Issues with ERD

Tags: database, ms-access, erd

[image: ERD, sorry for the bad quality!]I have been told by my tutor that there is an issue with my ERD, I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with it for a few hours now and can't get my head around it. I was just wondering if anyone can spot the issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join from the `Customer` table to the `Orders` table is not on the `CustomerID` primary key field.

Also, to adhere to database normalisation rules, `Products` would typically be linked to an order **line** table, as this avoids repeating order **header** information (such as Customer, Employee, Date etc.) for every product ordered.

Comment: Oh okay, so I should put the OrderID into customerID as a foreign key?

Comment: No, you should link from `CustomerID` in the `Customer` table to `Customer ID` in the `Orders` table; currently this join looks to be from either `First Name` or `Last Name`. You might also want to maintain consistency in your naming such that you have either `Customer` & `Order` or `Customers` and `Orders`; similarly whether you wish to use `CustomerID` or `Customer ID`.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean! Thanks for the help i really appreciate it!